# Besides "but", "however", "although", what words can be used to mean "in contrast to what was just said" in written English?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Besides "but", "however", "although", what words can be used to mean "in contrast to what was just said" in written English?

For example,

> Such analysis is challenging because it is high-dimensional and sparse, **however**; the result can be more useful and informative.

Can I use "nonetheless", "nevertheless", etc. Any other suggestions? Thanks!w

Comment: There are tons of expressions to create contrast. Yet, still, whereas, on the other hand, that said, on the contrary, ... But for your quoted sentence I would probably head in the direction of "nonetheless", "despite", "in spite of that", "anyway", "even so" -- something that affirms the first half of the sentence but says the second half balances, mitigates or outweighs it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Such analysis is challenging because it is high-dimensional and sparse**:** however; the result can be more useful and informative."

I do agree with Luke that one of the options he mentions is probably the appropriate one to use.

In addition to those you mentioned, the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/thesaurus/however) gives us:

> nevertheless, nonetheless, still, yet, though, even so, for all that, but for all that, despite that, but despite that, in spite of that, but in spite of that
>   anyway, anyhow, be that as it may, having said that, notwithstanding

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/however) yields:

> even so, howbeit, nevertheless, nonetheless, notwithstanding, still, still and all, though, withal, yet
>
> **Words related to *however***
>
> after all, anyhow, regardless